Handling duplicated data in SQL
I have a tables which are created and populated with millions of rows on a daily basis. There is no ID field, and rows are identified by the unique combination of field values. There is no possibility of redesigning the table.
Sometimes, these tables end up containing a complete duplicate set of rows which I don't want. However, there are also cases where duplicates are legitimate - on any normal day a few rows out of the millions may be duplicated, triplicated, or even quadruplicated. These I don't want to get rid of.
Till now, I have had a procedure to take the distinct set of rows, clear the table, and reinsert these distinct rows back in the table. This eliminates the complete duplications, however, this removes also the legitimate duplicates.
I have a new approach, using a cursor, to take a "grouped by" list of rows including a "count" field and insert the fields into a temp table based on the count field divided by the minimum value for "count". The table is then cleared out and repopulated with the contents of the temp table. This solves the problem completely, however it is at great cost of performance. It is a very slow solution.
My question is whether there is a set based approach to this problem which might speed it up. If the minimum count of rows in the grouped by table is 2, I would want to halve the number of all rows, if the minimum is 3, reduce to a third and so on. I cannot come up with an approach using sets that would do this.
Secondly, if imperative code is required because there is no set based solution, would it be preferable to process the data in a proper programming language (e.g. C#) rather than using SQL cursors?

How do you differentiate between legitimate duplicates and true duplicates?  Is it purely a manual review and setup?

@JonathanFite true duplicates affect the entire table. In this case, the entire table is duplicated (meaning the legitimate ones would become quadruplicated)

Are you able to redesign the process so that the new data gets loaded into a staging table? You mention that it's only "sometimes" that you get duplicates, so I can't see a set based approach unless you can clearly differentiate between "new load" and "existing", which would then let you better control the insert behavior.

Still unclear on how you differentiate between legitimate duplicate rows and duplicates you want removed. A sample table with example data of both cases would be immensely helpful for you to add to your Post, explaining why each case is the way it is.

Here is a possible start to a solution. Providing actual table, actual data , and expected result may change answer. As it is written, it will fail if all values are legitimate duplicates or if the duplicates do not span the entire data set.
The query will find the lowest count for all combinations. Legitimate duplicates will have a higher count.  It will then delete any rows where the modulus of the rownumber to min count does not equal Zero.
Create table and load data with legit duplicates and load this data 3 times, 18 rows in total.
CREATE TABLE #tmp(col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT);

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES(1,1,1),
(1,1,1),
(1,1,1),
(2,3,4),
(1,3,1),
(1,3,1);
GO 3


SELECT * FROM #tmp;

Now we use the Over clause to get the minimum count based on the unique set of columns. Then if the minimum count is greater than one, so we dont delete rows if there wasnt a full duplicate load, it will delete all rows where the rownumber divided by min count does not equal zero.
DECLARE @min INT;
--get min count
WITH cte AS(
SELECT  *,COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3) AS cnt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col1,col2,col3) AS rn
FROM    #tmp)

SELECT @min= MIN(cnt) 
FROM    cte;

--if @min > 1 so it doesnt delete if there are no full set duplicates
IF (@min > 1)
BEGIN
WITH cte AS(
SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col1,col2,col3) AS rn
FROM    #tmp)

DELETE
FROM    cte
WHERE rn % @min <> 0;
END;


SELECT  *
FROM    #tmp;

We should now have the desired 6 legit rows.
